Atiyah sequence of a coherent sheaf
I want to show that if $X$ is a smooth complex projective variety, then analytification induces an equivalence of categories between algebraic integrable connections on $X$ and analytic integrable connections on $X^\text{an}$. It does not follow immediately from GAGA that every analytic connection $(M, \nabla)$ comes from an algebraic connection, since $\nabla: M \to M \otimes \Omega^1_{X^\text{an}}$ is not $\mathcal{O}_{X^\text{an}}$-linear. A fix mentioned in this question is to view an integrable connection on $X^\text{an}$ as an $\mathcal{O}$-linear splitting of the Atiyah sequence
$$0 \mapsto \operatorname{End}(M) \to \operatorname{At}(M) \to \mathcal{T}_{X^\text{an}} \to 0$$
and apply GAGA.
I can't figure out what this exact sequence should be, and I couldn't find any references. What is $\operatorname{At}(\bullet)$, and what precisely is this exact sequence?

Why don't you look at Atiyah's original paper (Complex analytic connections in fibre bundles, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 85 (1957), 181-207)? It is very clearly written.

for a modern treatment you could try [0807.4374] Hermitian vector bundles and extension groups on arithmetic schemes. II. The arithmetic Atiyah extension

@abx Thank you for this! It seems that 0.4 is the dual of what I wrote here. What I don't get is the following: in the context of my question, I think $\operatorname{At}(M)$ should be the sheaf of differential operators on $M$ of degree $\leq 1$. But then what is the map to the tangent sheaf $T_{X^\text{an}}$ be?

Nevermind, I think I got it. It should be $D \mapsto ( f \mapsto \operatorname{tr}([D,f]))$, right?

I don't know what you call "$\operatorname{tr}$". Anyway, that map is called the symbol of a differential operator — you'll find the definition in any book on manifolds.

@abx I meant the trace of the $\mathcal{O}{X^\text{an}}$-linear endomorpism $[D,f]$ of $\mathcal{M}$. I am familiar with (principal) symbols in the case $\mathcal{M} = \mathcal{O}{X^\text{an}}$, but I have not found a reference discussing this for arbitrary coherent modules. Mimicking the usual construction, I do not see why the symbol would land in the tangent sheaf - shouldn't it land in the sheaf of derivations on $\mathcal{M}$?

The point is that $\operatorname{At}(M) $ is the sheaf of  differential operators on $M$ of degree $\leq 1$ with scalar symbol.

@abx Okay, now I get it, thanks a lot! That's exactly what was confusing me. I'll write up the argument as an answer to this question for future reference.

Here's how the argument goes, thanks to @abx. $\operatorname{At}(M)$ is given by $\mathbb{C}$-linear endomorphisms $D: M \to M$ for which the commutator $[D,f]$ given by $[D,f](m) := D(fm) - fD(m)$ acts via left multiplication by some element $h_{D,f} \in \mathcal{O}$. The map to the tangent sheaf $T$ is given by
$$D \mapsto (f \mapsto h_{D,f})$$
and it's straightforward to check that this is a derivation. It's clear that the kernel is $\operatorname{End}_{\mathcal{O}}(M)$, and surjectivity follows by defining
$$D_P\left( \sum_{i=1}^n f_i m_i\right) := \sum_{i=1}^n P(f_i) m_i$$
in some local basis $m_i$ of $M$, where $P \in T_X$. It is now immediate that $\mathcal{O}$-linear right splittings correspond to integrable connections on $M$.
